# How can I make this regulator output 2.8 V or 1.5 V?

Tags: voltage-regulator, lm317

I looked at an [LM317AG-TN3-R](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317a.pdf) which functions as a regulator. I'm trying to make sense of this part of the datasheet:

[image]

I don't quite understand how I can now get 2.8 V and 1.5 V respectively. How do I use the given equation?

Comment: Look in the datasheet for "adjustment pin current", that is IADJ. This is a small current that when multiplied by R2 is a small voltage, and that gets added to the much more significant factor 1.25(1 + R2/R1). Just pick a value for R2, around 1K, fill in your known values for IADJ and Vout and solve for R1.

Comment: In future, please do not post an image of part of one page of the data sheet  which cuts off the useful information **"Because the 100-μA current from the adjustment terminal represents an error term, the LM317A was designed to minimize IADJ and make it very constant with line and load changes. To do this, all quiescent operating current is returned to the output, establishing a minimum load current requirement. If there is insufficient load on the output, the output will rise."**

Comment: The LM317 is designed to maintain 1.5V across R1. This is a constant and does not change as long as the input voltage is sufficiently high. Therefore, a voltage across R2 will be developed by the sum of the current:  Iadj + 1.5/R1. The output voltage will be 1.5V plus the voltage across R2.

Comment: So am I able to get exactly 1.5V out of the LM317?

Comment: The reference is actually 1.25V. For 1.5V, you need to calculate a voltage divider as explained elsewhere.

Comment: You have to make it so that Vref is exactly 1.25V when Vout is exactly the voltage you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We'll need a schematic to help:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzZTio.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On page 6 of the datasheet you linked to, we are given a value for "minimum load current", which is typically 3.5 mA, but could be as much as 10 mA. We should design with the worst-case in mind, just in case you are unlucky enough to buy the crappiest LM317 ever made. That's 10 mA. Luckily R1 represents a load on the LM317's output, drawing current \$I_1\$, and can perform this function. Since R1 always has 1.25 V across it, we can use Ohm's law to find a value which will pass 10 mA:

$$ R_1 = \frac{1.25\text{ V}}{10\text{ mA}} = 125\Omega $$

Many implementations choose R1=240Ω, suggesting that those designers believe minimum required output current is more like 5 mA, which is not unreasonable given the datasheet's claim that it's "typically 3.5 mA". However, *if you can guarantee* that your load will *never* draw under 10 mA, then the value of R1 can be much higher still. The only requirement here is that the LM317's output must *always* source at least *some* current, around 10 mA, be that via R1 or your load.

Now you have eliminated one of the variables, R1, and the equation on page 1 of the datasheet may be rearranged and solved for R2:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_\text{OUT} &= 1.25 \left( 1 + \frac{R_2}{R_1} \right) + I_\text{ADJ}R_2 \\ \\
&= 1.25 + 1.25 \frac{R_2}{R_1} + I_\text{ADJ}R_2 \\ \\
1.25 \frac{R_2}{R_1} + I_\text{ADJ}R_2 &= V_\text{OUT}-1.25 \\ \\
1.25 R_2 + I_\text{ADJ}(R_1R_2) &= R_1(V_\text{OUT}-1.25) \\ \\
R_2(1.25 + I_\text{ADJ}R_1) &= R_1(V_\text{OUT}-1.25) \\ \\
R_2 &= \frac{R_1(V_\text{OUT}-1.25)}{1.25 + I_\text{ADJ}R_1} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Remembering that \$I_\text{ADJ} = 50\mu A\$ (see "Adjustment pin current" on datasheet page 6) and \$R_1 = 125\Omega\$, then for \$V_\text{OUT} = 1.5\text{ V}\$ just plug in those values:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R_2 &= \frac{R_1(V_\text{OUT}-1.25)}{1.25 + I_\text{ADJ}R_1} \\ \\
&= \frac{125(1.5-1.25)}{1.25 + 50 \times 10^{-6} \times 125} \\ \\
&= \frac{31.3}{1.26} \\ \\
&\approx 25\Omega
\end{aligned}
$$

You may have noticed that the term \$I_\text{ADJ}R_2\$ is small, because 50 μA is small compared to all other currents flowing. It is described as an "error term" on page 10 of the datasheet, due to this comparably tiny adjustment current, and contributes very little to the overall result. You would be justified in neglecting it entirely, in which case the above formulae simplify to:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_\text{OUT} &= 1.25 \left( 1 + \frac{R_2}{R_1} \right) \\ \\
R_2 &= \frac{R_1(V_\text{OUT}-1.25)}{1.25} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

I remind you that you could use R1=240 Ω or even greater if your load application draws 10 mA or more at all times, but this implies a commensurately greater R2. The term \$I_\text{ADJ}R_2\$ becomes more and more significant, the higher R2 goes, and at some point it will no longer be negligible.

Comment: Another reason they can get away with 240Ω is that the minimum output current goes up significantly with input voltage and often we can assume input voltage is not very high. At < 20V Vin-Vout typical minimum current is halved compared to the datasheet 40V. Worst case is very high Vin-Vout and very low temperature.

Answer (score 6):

It's fairly simple algebra to solve the equation for R2 then plug in the values of R1, Iadj and the required output voltage Vo to get the resistor value you need.
$$
R_2=\frac{R_1(V_\text{OUT} - 1.25 V)}{1.25\text{ V} + R_1 \times I_\text{ADJ}}
$$
In the datasheet TI uses R1 = 240 ohms. Using this value R2 = 47 ohms for Vo = 1.5 V and to get Vo = 2.8 V, R2 = 292 ohms (which is not a preferred value). Depending on the accuracy you require, probably 300 ohms would be OK.
For values of R1 around 240 ohms, ignoring the Iadj term only introduces about 2% difference and simplifies the calculation.

$$
R_2 = \frac{R_1(V_\text{OUT}-1.25\text{ V})}{1.25\text{ V}}
$$
As others have pointed out in their comments the LM317 requires a **minimum** load current of 5mA in order to maintain regulation. The LM317 maintains 1.25 V across R1, the 240 ohm resistor, to provide this minimum load even with any other load disconnected. So it serves the dual purpose of loading the regulator and establishing one half of the Vo setting voltage divider. If you want to save power by using a higher value for R1 then you must provide / guarantee that there is sufficient external load at all times in order to maintain the required regulation.

Comment: Those resistances seem pretty low. Try increasing an order of magnitude or two.

Comment: @Hearth As I said, 240 ohms is what TI use in most of their examples in the data sheet. There appears to be one incidence of 120 ohms and another of 480 ohms. Increasing the value to, say, 2K2 ohms means you really cannot ignore the Iadj term as it contributes 0.22V to ba added to 1.25V , nealy 18%.

Comment: One reason the resistances are low is because the LM317 requires a minimum load of several mA. With a small R1, R2 that requirement can be met without regard to the real load.

Comment: @PeterJennings And that would be why you generally want to use modern linear regulators, then, I assume. Throwing away even *more* power on the feedback network....